# kendo UI pagination

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, pagination

I have specific problem in which I have two datasources.  I want to reset the pagination to 1 when I switch drop-downs from **Recently Written** to **Recently Dined**.  I think the issue is since these are coming from two different data sources the pagination doesn't refresh instead it will stay on, as an example, page 2 even after I click on a different select drop down list.

the pagination happens here but I'm not sure how to "reset" it.[image: Recently Dined][image: Recently Written]

```
if (this.dataSource.totalPages() <= 1) {
    this.pager.element.hide();
}
else {
    this.pager.element.show();
}
```

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
(function ($) {

    var kendo = window.kendo;
    var ui = kendo.ui,
        Grid = ui.Grid,
        DATABOUND = "dataBound";
    var
        _init = kendo.ui.Grid.fn.init;


    var CompanyGrid = Grid.extend({
        init: function (element, options) {
            var that = this;

            Grid.fn.init.call(that, element, options);

            // register custom dataBound
            that._registerDataBound();
        },
        _registerDataBound: function () {
            var that = this;

            that.bind(DATABOUND, function(e) {
                if (!this.pager) {
                  return;
                }
                // Hides page arrows if <= 1 page
                if (this.dataSource.totalPages() <= 1) {
                    this.pager.element.hide();
                }
                else {
                    this.pager.element.show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    ui.plugin(VengaGrid);
}(jQuery));
```

});

Here's the documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/pager
**Update**

I tried

```
 if (this.dataSource.totalPages() <= 1) {
    this.pager.element.hide();
} else {
    this.pager.page(1);
}

and got this
 <error>jquery.min.js:1 p.Eventjquery.min.js:14 p.Eventjquery.min.js:14 p.event.fixjquery.min.js:14 p.event.dispatchjquery.min.js:14 p.event.add.g.handle.h
jquery.min.js:14 <error>
3jquery.min.js:1 <error>
2jquery.min.js:1 <error>
86jquery.min.js:14 <error>
jquery.js?body=1:347 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call dataSource.page(0); after you switch dataSources

Comment: Where should I call this at?

Comment: just tried calling `this.pager.page(1)` after `this.pager.element.show()` and it doesn't seem to work.  `this.pager` is a kendo object but as soon as I call `.element` it turns into a javascript object.

Comment: like I said in the answer, you need to call it on the datasource, not the pager.

Comment: thanks, I should have followed more closely. So it works in the console once I put debugger in the code after the `else` statement, but I'm not sure what's happening once debugger is removed...you can view the stack-trace here  [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/SOHrdrs.png), at the end it says " Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded."  I dunno, I feel like I've tried debugging to no end.  Would appreciate more assistance but, of course not expected.

Comment: look up "kendo ui refresh datasource"

Comment: I guess the other thought is: why are you extending the grid widget to register a custom databound event? The grid widget has a databound event you can use by default:  (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound)